# Не грузится программы в Windows 10

Tags: windows

Не получается скачать хоть какие-либо приложения (программы, игры, десктопы и т.д.) на Windows 10. При попытке загрузить (скачать) что либо, просто стоит без никаких изменений. Перепробовал все, но пока без полезно.
Помогите пожалуйста, если кто-нибудь знает как можно решить данную проблему.

Comment: Если речь о скачивании через браузер, то для начала попробуйте отключить полностью все плагины и открыть страницу, на которой скачиваете в режиме Инкогнито

Comment: @Coder попробуй добавить нового пользователя Windows и зайди под ним в систему

Answer (score 1):

1. Попробуйте использовать другой браузер.
2. В зависимости от принадлежности ресурса скачивания к той или иной стране - подключите\отключите vpn.
3. Для установки на локальном компьютере пользователю должны быть назначены права администратора.